# How did these duplicate questions occur?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

A user managed to post two copies of the question at the same time.

[Hi, I'm getting this error MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70931256/hi-im-getting-this-error-mysqldb-exceptions-programmingerror-not-enough-argu)

[Hi, I'm getting this error MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70931255/hi-im-getting-this-error-mysqldb-exceptions-programmingerror-not-enough-argu)

The question IDs differ by 1.

Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: When answering sometimes the UI to says: *"Ups an error occurred please try again"* so you take the opportunity to edit a little more and press the submit button a second time... then you suddenly see the answer was posted twice, the 1st time despite the UI warning about an error the submit went through. I'm guessing the same happened for the question. (Something to do with no server-side check to close the editor client-side...)

Comment: The post times were exactly the same to the second, so I don't think that's what happened here. Isn't there also a check for duplicate titles? Is that based on a cache that hadn't been updated yet?

Comment: Honestly don't know, I'm a bit annoyed by this because it's happened to me several times posting answers... But I'm still waiting for someone to answer Sonic's post (there's not much that can be said without staff lending their knowledge.)

Comment: This hasn't received an answer so here's a guess: there's a strange hardware driven bug that can happen, if you have a defective mouse clicking once can electrically be two separate clicks just miliseconds apart - I've seen applications that weren't robust against this followed by bug reports where neither users nor developers could reproduce the issue and were left wondering. (This is different from the bug that issues a warning and might need adding a minimum on-release to the buttons.)

Comment: @bad_coder It didn't receive an answer because it's a duplicate of an old question.

Comment: yeah I know, the duplicate target also doesn't have an answer... that's what I meant to say.

Comment: Obviously they submitted twice, the point is to raise the issue of the bug that doesn't detect the duplicate submission.

Comment: @bad_coder: That is important input (defective mouse). An [Arduino Leonardo](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-leonardo-with-headers) (or the equivalent) may be used to reproduce such a problem. The [Stack Overflow copy/paste "keyboard"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/) is [QMK](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/hardware_avr)-based, so it may be able to do it as well ([sample](https://getreuer.info/posts/keyboards/mouse-turbo-click/index.html)).